# Cycle through values in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to cycle through values in an array in python, I dont know how to do this.

```
pid = {
    "021554",
    "098765",
    "287004",
    "237655"
}
```

Above is my array, im trying to use `pid` to put it in a link, for example:

```
get("www.google.com/" + pid)
```

I want it to use pid number 1 then number 2 then number 3 and so till it goes back to the top of the list and starts again in an else if.

```
if 'text' in response.text:
    do something
else:
    use next pid to add to the link and start script from the top again using the new id`
```

Comment: That is not an array, that is a `set`. You almost certainly didn't mean to use a Python `array.array` or a `numpy.ndarray` anyway, but a normal python `list`.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.cycle`

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you using some sort of library for your `get` function, like `requests`? I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes im using requests i just didn't include it all it would obviously it would be

`s = requests.session()

s.get(url + pid)`

Comment: It is further unclear, though, exactly the behavior you expect. You want this to keep repeating forever?

Comment: yes i want it to always run

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import cycle
import requests

for pid in cycle("021554 098765 287004 237655".split()):
    url = "www.google.com/{}".format(pid)
    txt = requests.get(url).text
    if "something" in txt:
        break
```

Do be aware that this could run forever if "something" doesn't show up.